# Mapping problem between 2.78a and 2.78b

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

I use spot lamp as projector with concentric circles.
(mapping wave texture, normal coordinates, rotation via driver)
The same scene give wrong results with blender 2.78b
2.78a is good

Is it some new blender mapping technique or bug?

[image: same scene 2.78b and 2.78a]